# How to MANUALLY call static block from another static block in magento?

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.8, magento2, admin, static-block

How can I call a static block from another static block **manually** because i have a **customized theme**.

I also set block from Magento admin panel, it's working but I dont need this admin method

I think I have to put some static block code in the WYSIWYG editor of the static block admin pannel but which code is it?

Comment: Can you explain what you mean with " I dont need this admin method" ? I'm not exactly sure what you are trying to achieve and how.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

to output a static block inside another static block, you basically can do two things:

1. Insert a Widget:

   - in the Editor toolbar, click on insert Widget (2. from the left)
   - Choose Static Block
   - Choose the Block you want to insert

you should end up with a code like this (if you hide the wysiwyg editor)

> {{widget type="cms/widget_block" template="cms/widget/static_block/default.phtml" block_id="1"}}

2. Insert a cms Block directly:

> {{block type="cms/block" block_id="your_block_id"}}

Comment: ThankYou Mr.David Verholen